# How to share a file over "Windows Share" protocol from scientific linux?

Tags: files, filesystems, samba, file-sharing, scientific-linux

I have a file on my linux. I want to share it via "Windows Share" (IPMI can understand only one way of remote large files mounting). How to share my file over "Windows Share" from my scientific linux?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about "Windows Share", do you mean the SMB protocol? I access files hosted on CentOS from Windows 7/8 machines with samba.  No client side installation needed.

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch03.html